Using Dehn invariant to prove an octahedron cannot be dissected into a regular tetrahedron.

Show that an octahedron cannot be dissected into a regular
tetrahedron.

By using Dehn invariant, I already proved the following results:

An octahedron cannot be dissected into a cube
A tetrahedron cannot be dissected into a cube

Note: any two figures equivalent by dissection must have the same Dehn invariant.
Also, I proved some related results:

$(a,\alpha)=0\iff a=0$ or $\alpha$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$.
The invariant of a cube  of any size is $0$.
The invariant of a tetrahedron of size $a$ is $6(a,\alpha)$ with $\cos\alpha=\dfrac{1}{3}$.
The invariant of a octahedron of size $a$ is $12(a,\alpha)$ with $\cos\alpha=-\dfrac{1}{3}$.

Could someone help me prove the main problem? Thanks in advance
